# Using Python add-in wizard with ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, arcgis-10.3

I'd like to create an add-in for ArcMap (ArcGIS 10.3) using Python. Unfortunately, [the wizard](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5f3aefe77f6b4f61ad3e4c62f30bff3b) does not seem to have been updated for 10.3, which is the only version Esri provides for download at present (AFAIK). I don't have any other version installed, and never did because I'm starting fresh on a new PC.

Is there a wizard for 10.3?

If not, is there good documentation about what the wizard did for 10.1 and 10.2? If it only creates an XML document supplying the metadata and the name of the Python class to be instantiated on button-push, I'm sure I can replicate that. I just can't find any detailed information from ESRI; [the help documents discuss the wizard as though it is the only option](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/).

Comment: I've used that same wizard at 10.3 without encountering any issues.

Comment: @PolyGeo When I run it, the `Add-In Contents` panel comes up with nothing. That is, the first image in [this help document](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/button/014p0000001z000000/) is not the same. `Extensions`, `Menus` and `Toolbars` all have no contents.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. Did not realise you had to right click the item! Please close and publicly shame me.

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup I think it's just bad UI, your question is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was stupid and did not read the instructions correctly. I thought I had a version problem because the documentation was listed for ArcGIS 10.1 and the tutorial images did not match expectations (items were missing from the wizard).

Turns out I just had to right-click to be presented with the "missing" options.

Comment: Incidentally, the source of the add-in wizard is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/jasonbot/addin-wizard). It's a wee wxPython application, and does not even require ArcGIS to be installed.